# Set path to output directory for generated openapi yaml file using swagger and gradle

Tags: java, gradle, swagger, openapi, springdoc

When I run the app, an openapi yaml file is generated in target: projectName/build

But I wanna  generate yaml file in my own package named 'doc'

I have next dependency in build.gradle:

`implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:$openapiVersion"`

also my code application.yaml:

swagger/openapi settings

```
Springdoc:
  show-actuator: false
  swagger-ui:
    url: "/v3/api-docs"
    deep-linking: true
    display-operation-id: false
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
    default-models-expand-depth: -1
    default-model-expand-depth: 1
    default-model-rendering: example
    display-request-duration: false
    doc-expansion: none
    filter: false
    operations-sorter: alpha
    show-extensions: false
    show-common-extensions: false
    syntax-highlight:
      activated: true
      theme: monokai
```